# "If a function has an antiderivative, then it is continuous." What conditions can we add to make this true?

Tags: real-analysis

**Definition.** We say that a function $f$ is *antidifferentiable* or *has an antiderivative* if there exists a function $g$ such that $g^{\prime}=f$.

We know that [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559702/) is true:

**Proposition.** *Suppose a function is defined on an interval with more than one number. If that function is continuous, then it is antidifferentiable.*

---

What about the converse:

**Conjecture.** *Suppose a function is defined on an interval with more than one number. If that function is antidifferentiable, then it is continuous.*

Update: Turns out that Wikipedia has [something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Of_non-continuous_functions) about this, including several counterexamples showing that the above Conjecture is false. Nonetheless, I still have this question:

**Question.** What conditions can we add to above Conjecture to make it true?

Comment: consider [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I thought the step function isn't antidifferentiable?

Comment: the step function is not *differentiable*, but it's the derivative of the [ramp function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: But it isn't because the ramp function isn't differentiable (in particular at $0$).

Comment: the step function is integrable meaning you can calculate the definite integral on any closed interval around the step, as the sum of areas of two rectangles. however is not continuous at the step

Comment: A function is ‘anti differentiable’ iff it is a derivative. A derivative satisfies the Intermediate Value Property (conclusion of the IVT) but may fail to be continuous with standard example of $g=f’$ where $f=x^2 \sin (1/x)$ or something like that

Comment: Lookup meagre set, baire category theory.

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Of_non-continuous_functions

Comment: What you are esssentially asking here is "how to ensure that a derivative is continuous". As mentioned by @CalvinKhor derivatives possess intermediate value property. Combine that with monotone nature and you get continuity for free. Thus if $f$ is monotone and possesses an anti-derivative then $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 5):

**No** - though you are right in thinking that a counterexample is a bit hard to construct: in particular, something like a step function such as

$$f_1 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ f_1(x) := \begin{cases} 0\ \mbox{if $x < 0$}, \\1\ \mbox{if $x \ge 0$}\end{cases}$$

is *not* antidifferentiable on its whole domain, because at all domain points except $0$, any antiderivative of such a function has to satisfy

$${F_1}_\mathrm{putative}(x) = \begin{cases} C_1\ \mbox{if $x < 0$}\\x + C_2\ \mbox{if $x > 0$}\end{cases}$$

for some constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ - but there is *no* way to define a value exactly *at* $0$ that will make this differentiate to $f_1$ there, because this function is simply not differentiable at $0$ (the closest you can get is if $C_1 = C_2 = C$, and then if you define it such that ${F_1}_\mathrm{putative}(0) = C$, it will be continuous; but it is not differentiable there as it has a corner there).

Instead, you have to get a bit cleverer. A standard counterexample is (if I remember right)

$$f_2: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f_2(x) := \begin{cases} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ \mbox{if $x \ne 0$}\\ 0\ \mbox{if $x = 0$} \end{cases}$$

The antiderivatives of this function satisfy

$$F_2(x) = \begin{cases}x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \mathrm{Ci}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + C\ \mbox{if $x \ne 0$}\\
C\ \mbox{if $x = 0$}\end{cases}$$

including at $x = 0$, for some constant $C$. It can be checked that these functions are differentiable at $x = 0$, with derivative $F'_2(0) = 0$.

---

**ADD:** Looks like I remembered wrong - commenters above showed as more "standard" example that where we start with $F_3(x) := \begin{cases}x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\  \mbox{if $x \ne 0$}\\ 0\ \mbox{if $x = 0$}\end{cases}$ as *antiderivative* ... but meh! The above works and its exposition to me follows the direction of the implication in the question better: construct a weird "derivative" and then try and antidifferentiate it.