# What is an antiderivative for $\frac{1}{1+3\cos^{2}x}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Define $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+3\cos^{2}x}$.

[Since](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559702/) $f$ is continuous, $f$ has an antiderivative. That is, there exists some function $F:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $F^{\prime}=f$.

Using the substitution $u=\tan x$ and doing some work, we find that a possible antiderivative of $f$ is the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan x}{2}$.

However, the problem with $g$ is that it's not defined at odd multiples of $\pi/2$, while the $F$ we're seeking is defined on $\mathbb R$.

So, what is $F$ and how do we find it?

(Or is there a mistake somewhere in my argument above?)

Comment: I won't mark this one as a duplicate since the question statements are rather different, but the issue is exactly the same as the one in this question, which has good* answers taking various approaches, involving a similar integral: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275770/how-to-integrate-int-02-pi-frac1-sin4x-cos4-x-dx/3275818 (*One of the answers is mine, I make no claims about its goodness.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each odd integer $k$, define $f_k:((k-2)\pi/2,k\pi/2) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $f_k(x)=\frac{1}{1+3\cos^{2}x}$.

As you've found, an antiderivative of $f_k$ is $g_k:((k-2)\pi/2,k\pi/2) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $g_k(x)=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan x}{2}$.

And as you've also correctly stated, we know by the FTC that $f$ *must* have an antiderivative $F$.

So, we guess that such a function $F$ can be constructed by "moving up or down" the functions $g_k$ and "stitching" them together, and also "filling in the holes" at each odd multiple of $\pi/2$.

By examining the graphs of each $g_k$, we come up with this guess:

For each odd integer $k$, define $F$ by
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
\left(k-1\right)\frac{\pi}{2}, & \text{ for }x=\left(k-2\right)\frac{\pi}{2},\\
\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan x}{2}+k\frac{\pi}{4}, & \text{ for }x\in\left(\left(k-2\right)\frac{\pi}{2},k\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
k\frac{\pi}{2}, & \text{ for }x=k\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{cases},$$

To show that the above guess is correct, we can verify that $F^{\prime}=f$ (this will involve more work).

---

Similar questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264947/), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248282/), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248715/). See also Jeffrey and Rich ([1994](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/174603.174409), "The Evaluation of Trigonometric Integrals Avoiding Spurious Discontinuities") and Jeffrey ([1994](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cms_upload/0025570x43754.di021186.02p0083t.pdf), "The Importance of Being Continuous").